# Remove ESDTRoleBurnForAll role from collection

Tags: multiversx

I created a collection and Anyone -> `ESDTRoleBurnForAll` role is coming by default.

What does this role do and how can I remove it from the collection?

Answer (score 0):

The role says that anyone can locally burn his/her tokens.

Here you can find a log message:
https://github.com/multiversx/mx-sdk-js-core/blob/feat/next/src/transactionsFactories/tokenManagementTransactionsFactory.ts#L598

> You are about to issue (register) a new token. This will set the role "`ESDTRoleBurnForAll`" (globally).
> Once the token is registered, you can unset this role by calling "`unsetBurnRoleGlobally`" (in a separate transaction).

So, you can unset the role with this transaction:
https://github.com/multiversx/mx-sdk-js-core/blob/feat/next/src/transactionsFactories/tokenManagementTransactionsFactory.ts#L270

```
createTransactionForUnsettingBurnRoleGlobally(options: {
    sender: IAddress;
    tokenIdentifier: string;
}): TransactionNext {
    const dataParts = ["unsetBurnRoleGlobally", utf8ToHex(options.tokenIdentifier)];

    return new TransactionNextBuilder({
        config: this.config,
        sender: options.sender,
        receiver: Address.fromBech32(ESDT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS),
        dataParts: dataParts,
        gasLimit: this.config.gasLimitToggleBurnRoleGlobally,
        addDataMovementGas: true,
    }).build();
}
```